# CORS headers present on /connect but not /negotiate

Tags: asp.net, cors, signalr

I'm using SignalR with websockets, I have this code in my `Startup` class's `Configuration` method:

```
        appBuilder.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);                
            map.RunSignalR(signalRConfig);
        });
```

I noticed `/signalr/negotiate` is called first, and the response does not have any `Access-Control` headers:

[image]

However, the `/signalr/connect` response does:

[image]

Why doesn't `/signalr/negotiate` have those headers too?

My web app is running under `https://localhost:4200`.

Why is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `https://localhost:4200` and not `*`?

According to the [sourcecode](https://github.com/julianpaulozzi/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/CorsOptions.cs#L14), it should allow any origin, not just the webapp that initiated the call to SignalR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS does not apply to WebSocket requests. The CORS middleware might be incorrectly add those headers to the WebSocket response (but it doesn't cause any harm, it's just headers).

For the negotiate request, there should be an OPTIONS request in the network tab which will contain the CORS headers, the network request you're looking at is the actual GET which is sent after a successful OPTIONS request.

Comment: Don't websocket requests start off as HTTP requests though?

Comment: Sure, but it still doesn't apply. If you were using ASP.NET Core (which it looks like you aren't), you could add the WebSocket origin restriction to simulate CORS with WebSockets: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0#websocket-origin-restriction